# Insert invalid date value using Jdbc template update method

Tags: java

I am trying to execute an insert query using Spring JDBC template update method with the invalid date value 2015-13-94. After executing the insert query the value is changing to 2015-04-04 and updating into table. But when I try to insert the invalid date value using DB2 I am getting error. Please let us know is there any internal logic in jdbc template update method to convert invalid date value.

Comment: Please add the code you use for insertion.

Comment: Object[] inputValues=getInputValues(ratingItemFactorAmt,projectId,exhibitCd,varCount,exhibitData,rateSearchCriteria,referenceExhibit,columnDataList,columnNameList);
  try{
   return jdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery,inputValues);
  }

Comment: You can edit the question placing your code there. Post also the insertQuery and the date variable value.

Comment: INSERT INTO IRP.WRK_TRATING_NOTICE ( IRP_PROJECT_ID , VERSION_NAME , ENDORS_NUM , ENDORS_EDITION_NUM , TST_CRIT_CD , TST_VALUE1 , LMT_DED_VALUE , PRINT_DISPLAY_FORMAT , MIN_RNG_PCT , MAX_RNG_PCT , VALUE_PCT , MIN_RNG_AMT , MAX_RNG_AMT , VALUE_AMT , RATE_REVISION_DT , RATING_EXHIBIT_CD , LAST_UPDATED_USER_ID , LAST_UPDATED_DTSTMP  ) VALUES ( '52821762' , '11', '313065' , '412' ,'C-CHK' ,'13033' , '0' , 'AMT-RNG-FMT' , '1' , '1', '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '2015-13-94', 'A_RAN' , 'USWMCS43' , '2015-05-13 13:29:47.974'  ) here the 2015-13-94 is invalid date value i am trying to insert.

Comment: Can any one  reply to above question?